# Kotlin - Get new index of item in shuffled list

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, shuffle

I have a multiple choice quiz with 4 choices per answer. In the ArrayList with the questions and choices, the correct answer is set to the index of the correct option. I want to shuffle the choices but am not sure how to identify the new index of the correct answer. Any thoughts?

Question object

```
object ConstantsAnalysis {
        const val TOTAL_CORRECT: String = "total_correct"
        const val TOTAL_OPP: String = "total_opp"
        fun getQuestions3(): ArrayList<Questions3> {
            val questionList = ArrayList<Questions3>()
            val q1 = Questions3(1, null,
                "On a graph, the horizontal line along which data are plotted is the _____",
                "y axis", "x axis", "origin", "quadrant", 2, R.string.Jones_1995, null)
questionList.addAll(listOf(q1))
            questionList.shuffle()
            return questionList
        }
    }
```

Data class

```
data class Questions3(
    val id: Int, val image: Int?, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String,
    val option3: String, val option4: String, val correctAnswer: Int, val dialogBox: Int?, val dialogBox2: Int?)
```

Shuffle choices

```
val ansorder = arrayOf(question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4)
        ansorder.shuffle()
        radio_button1.text = ansorder[0]
        radio_button2.text = ansorder[1]
        radio_button3.text = ansorder[2]
        radio_button4.text = ansorder[3]
```

Check answer choice

```
if (questions3!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition) {
//do x
}
```

Edit (Since `correct answer` is a string and the index changes after shuffling, `answerView(questions3.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border`.

```
class QuestionsActivityAnalysis : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mCurrentPosition:Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList:ArrayList<Questions3>? = null
    private var mSelectedOptionPosition:Int = 0
    private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0
    private var mSelectedOptionText: String? = null

private fun shuffle() {
        val question = mQuestionsList!![mCurrentPosition - 1]
        val ansorder = arrayOf(question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4)
        ansorder.shuffle()
        radio_button1.text = ansorder[0]
        radio_button2.text = ansorder[1]
        radio_button3.text = ansorder[2]
        radio_button4.text = ansorder[3]
    }

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.radio_button1 -> { selectedOptionView(radio_button1, 1)
                mSelectedOptionText = radio_button1.text as String?
            }
            R.id.radio_button2 -> { selectedOptionView(radio_button2, 2)
                mSelectedOptionText = radio_button2.text as String?
            }
            R.id.radio_button3 -> { selectedOptionView(radio_button3, 3)
                mSelectedOptionText = radio_button3.text as String?
            }
            R.id.radio_button4 -> { selectedOptionView(radio_button4, 4)
                mSelectedOptionText = radio_button4.text as String?
            }

R.id.btn_submit -> {
val questions3 = mQuestionsList?.get(mCurrentPosition - 1)
                    if (questions3!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionText) {
} else {
                        mCorrectAnswers++
                    }
                    answerView(questions3.correctAnswer, R.drawable.correct_option_border)

private fun answerView(answer: Int, drawableView: Int) {
        when(answer){
            1 -> {
                radio_button1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
            }
            2 -> {
                radio_button2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
            }
            3 -> {
                radio_button3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
            }
            4 -> {
                radio_button4.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableView)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend just creating a data class like this:

```
data class QuestionOption(val question:String, val isCorrect = false)
```

Afterwards you can shuffle any way you like and just check if the selected QuestionOption has isCorrect set to true. You get a bunch of benefits and the logic gets simpler.

Edit:

To make it easier to declare questions this way:

In general if you add questions in your code you want only as much necessary code as required. For this you can either declare a good constructor or a  function that basically maps your values to a constructor. In your case I'd say

```
data class Questions3(
    val id: Int, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String,
    val option3: String, val correctOption: String, val image: Int?=null,val dialogBox1: Int?=null,val dialogBox2: Int?=null)
```

(notice how the optional parameters are last, you don't need to specify them as well thanks to them beeing null by default)

Makes sense, in theory you could also (not too clean but easy) just shuffle option 1-3 & correctOption and then just compare if the correctOption String matches the selected String.

Otherwise as I said, you can always create logic for mapping stuff. Here you can either map from Constructor to another Constructor, same with Functions that return a finished Object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Given the number of questions I have written, I'm hoping to avoid rewriting to split into separate classes. Would I be able to do something like `data class QuestionOption(val question:String, val answer1: String, val isCorrect = false, val answer2: String, val isCorrect = true, val answer3: String, val isCorrect = false, val answer4: String, val isCorrect = false)`

Comment: I would recommend still creating the data class but if you are concerned about too much code, you can just create a function that automatically creates questions in a short manner. See edit for more info

Comment: Added another way to solve it as well, would still implement a shorter Questions3 class either way

Comment: Changing the code per your edit yields the error `!= cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Int'`. Converting the string to int crashes the app (see my edit).

Comment: You should compare the selected Text with the Text of correctAnswer. Meaning questions3!!.correctAnswer == selectedAnswerText

Comment: After shuffling, how can I identify the new position of the correct answer? I'd like to use a drawable to indicate which answer is the correct answer. I can't seem to access the shuffled list from the function I need to reference it. I've edited my answer to help show what I mean.

Comment: I'd recommend creating an array with the 4 views, then using the foreach method to get the text and compare it with the correct answer. If it's correct you already have access to the view in the foreach and can just change the background there, less code as well